# Integrability (and hence regularity) of $\alpha$-harmonic maps

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, morse-theory, harmonic-functions

To prove the smoothness of an $\alpha$-harmonic map, Sachs and Uhlenbeck firstly show (in their paper "The existence of minimal immersions of 2-spheres") that it is in the Sobolev space $L^2_2(M,N)$, then show that it is also in $L^4_2(M,N)$. Finally, they use 'elliptic bootstrapping' to show that it is smooth.

My question is why it is in $L^4_2(M,N)$, $M$ being a compact surface. To show this, they start from the Euler-Lagrange equation satisfied by the $\alpha$-harmonic map $s$ and consider the 'linear operator' $\Delta_s \colon L^4_2(M,N) \to L^4_0(M,N)$, where
$$\Delta_su=\Delta u + (\alpha-1)(\langle d^2u,ds \rangle)ds/(1+|ds|^2)$$

They mention that since $\Delta_s$ has a nice inverse, one has $s \in L^4_2(M,N)$, but give no details. Can someone give a detailed proof of this statement? J. D. Moore gives an outline of the proof in his book "Introduction to Global Analysis - minimal surfaces in Riemannian manifolds", pp.214-5. He essentially says $A(s)(ds,ds)$ is in $L^4_0$, $A$ being the second fundamential form of $N$ in some Euclidean space, and prove that $\Delta_s$ is invertible and hence surjective, so $s$ is in $L^4_2(M,N)$.

I do not understand the proof, due to the following:

(1) $\Delta_s$ is not a 'linear operator', since $L^4_2(M,N)$ is a manifold.

(2) It seems $\Delta_s$ is not injective, since the operator maps all constant maps (to $N$) to $0$.

(3) $A(s)(ds,ds)$ may not be in $L^4_0(M,N)$, because the former is normal to $T_{s(x)}N$, $x \in M$. So, it may be some other $L^4_0$ spaces instead.

Comment: I took the liberty to fix some of the LaTeX, I hope you don't mind. Maybe have a look if everything is as intended.

Comment: Could they possibly mean that the map is to $L^4(M, \mathbb R^n)$ where $N \subset \mathbb R^n$? This is a linear space, and contains the tangent spaces of $N$ as subspaces.

Comment: You can see a proof with some more details in Colding Minicozzi's minimal surfaces book, Lemma 4.29

Comment: @M.G., thank you.

Comment: @Aidan, yes, it's possible. But still the Laplace type operator seems not injective and one has to show that it is surjective. I am not sure it is surjective.

Comment: @Otis, Colding and Minicozzi only show that the map is in $L^\alpha_2(M,N)$, with $\alpha$ just larger than 1.  I think we need to show, as indicated by Sachs and Uhlenbeck, the map is in $L^4_2(M,N)$.  That's why I ask this question.

Comment: We need the $L^4$ to start the 'elliptic bootstrapping' process.